# PHP (Symfony 4) rabbitmq consumer command as daemon

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, daemon, systemd

I have RabbitMQ producer and consumer written in PHP (Symfony 4). Consumer is working as custom symfony 4 command along with bundle **php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle**

Here is issue. I want to be able to set consumer to listen and consume tasks instantly after they appear in queue.

I tried to run it as one-shot systemd service but it's **not working** wery well.

Systemd:

```
[Unit]
Description=consumer for rabbitmq

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh /var/www/public/rabbit.sh
ExecStop=/usr/bin/pkill -f "rabbitmq:consumer"
RemainAfterExit=yes
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If there is better solution than writing daemon please let me know. I just want to be able to set consumer to listen and consume task instantly after it apear in queue.

Comment: You could run the batch consumer command `rabbitmq:batch:consumer` in the background as daemon, maybe set it to quit after a memory limit is reached and have supervisord automatically restart the deamon after that. When you do this, you will always have a consumer running in the background for new messages.

Comment: "I want to be able to set consumer to listen and consume tasks instantly after they appear in queue" - Unless I am missing something here but the consumer command already works that way! e.g. When you run `bin/console rabbitmq:consumer -m 5 your_queue` the relevant consumer will consume messages as soon as they come in. Check [this](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/06yq/handling-beanstalk-and-rabbitmq-workers-of-symfony-applications-with-supervisor-in-capistrano-deployment-process) for supervisor controller RabbitMQ consumers. And http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/rabbitmq

Comment: @BentCoder but in your case consumer consumes 5 messages and dies, I want it to consume infinite ammount of messages and run it with startup of my system

Comment: That's why you need to use supervisor. PHP is not the best when it comes to long running processes hence reason run your commands for limited amount numbers/jobs - e.g. 100. When the command dies, supervisor will start it again which is what exactly you need. This is how things are done. All you are goinv to do is, copy and paste job from the first link I've sent you.

Comment: @BentCoder thank you for help, supervisor is working very well for me :D

Comment: @el.luke That's good. I've added an example below so that if people wonder how it can be done, it would help them too so please accept it too to make it obvious please. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The solution to your "issue" is simple. All you are going to do is, make use of [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) which will watch your command behind the scene and bring it back up if it goes down.

PHP is not good at long running processes so you want to keep your consumer/worker to consume reasonably enough (not many) messages. e.g. 100 to 200 is good enough.

This is what you are going to do:

1. Create a supervisor config file for your command - check example below. If you wish go to the doc and read what exactly the properties below do.
2. Enable this config within the supervisor.

That's all!

```
[program:name-of-your-command]
command=php bin/console rabbitmq:consumer -m 100 your_queue --env=prod -DFOREGROUND # Your consumer command
directory=/path/to/your/app
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=5
startsecs=0
user=deployer # Your user
numprocs=1 # This tells supervisor to run only one consumer
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
stderr_logfile=/path/to/your/app/var/logs/%(program_name)s_stderr.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
stdout_logfile=/path/to/your/app/var/logs/%(program_name)s_stdout.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
```

Examples:

- [Handling beanstalk and RabbitMQ workers of symfony applications with supervisor in capistrano deployment process](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/06yq/handling-beanstalk-and-rabbitmq-workers-of-symfony-applications-with-supervisor-in-capistrano-deployment-process)
- [Using supervisor within docker containers](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/6tik/using-supervisor-within-docker-containers)
- [Monitoring processes with Supervisor](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/bn7g/monitoring-processes-with-supervisor)

Comment: This is very useful, thanks.  Do you mind if I ask what the `-DFOREGROUND` does? I haven't seen that before.